# How do I set an alarm to terminate an EC2 instance using boto?

Tags: amazon-ec2, alarm, boto, terminate, amazon-cloudwatch

I have been unable to find a simple example which shows me how to use boto to terminate an Amazon EC2 instance using an alarm (without using AutoScaling). I want to terminate the specific instance that has a CPU usage less than 1% for 10 minutes.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import boto.ec2
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
from boto.ec2.cloudwatch import MetricAlarm

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1", aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
cw = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region("us-east-1", aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for r in reservations:
    for inst in r.instances:
        alarm = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.MetricAlarm(name='TestAlarm', description='This is a test alarm.', namespace='AWS/EC2', metric='CPUUtilization', statistic='Average', comparison='<=', threshold=1, period=300, evaluation_periods=2, dimensions={'InstanceId':[inst.id]}, alarm_actions=['arn:aws:automate:us-east-1:ec2:terminate'])
        cw.put_metric_alarm(alarm)
```

Unfortunately it gives me this error:

> dimensions={'InstanceId':[inst.id]}, alarm_actions=['arn:aws:automate:us-east-1:ec2:terminate'])
>   TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alarm_actions'

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Also, I am not using CloudFormation, so I cannot use the AutoScaling feature. This is because I don't want the alarm to use a metric across the entire group, rather only for a specific instance, and only terminate that specific instance (not any instance in that group).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The alarm actions are not passed through dimensions but rather added as an attribute to the MetricAlarm object that you are using. In your code you need to do the following:

```
alarm = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.MetricAlarm(name='TestAlarm', description='This is a test alarm.', namespace='AWS/EC2', metric='CPUUtilization', statistic='Average', comparison='<=', threshold=1, period=300, evaluation_periods=2, dimensions={'InstanceId':[inst.id]})
alarm.add_alarm_action('arn:aws:automate:us-east-1:ec2:terminate')
cw.put_metric_alarm(alarm)
```

You can also see in the boto documentation here:

http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html#module-boto.ec2.cloudwatch.alarm

Comment: Now I'm getting the error:     `cw.put_metric_alarm(alarm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.0-py2.6.egg/boto/ec2/cloudwatch/__init__.py", line 545, in put_metric_alarm
    'Dimensions.member.%s.%s')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.0-py2.6.egg/boto/ec2/cloudwatch/__init__.py", line 237, in build_list_params
    params[label % i] = item
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: It turns out I was using boto 2.0, which isn't the latest version. Once I updated to 2.25.0, it worked fine using the way I had it originally.  Thanks though!

Comment: For future reference, the available automatic alarm actions are listed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingAlarmActions.html

Comment: @Rico For my case, EC2 instance is lying under instance groups of EMR. I can pass bootstrap action to create alarm on given instanceId, and "CPUUtilization"(whatever you mentioned.) But, in Bootstrapping time, there is no dimension present of given instanceId. Can you suggest some solution for my use-case ?