# AWS CloudWatch Alarm On Startup Of New EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to apply a CloudWatch alarm to instances as they are being created. The alarm should send a message to an email account when CPU usage drops below 10% for 1 full day. I believe the best way of achieving this is by using a User data script at the time of launching the instance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could use User Data to create the **CloudWatch Alarm and notification**.

Start by creating an **Amazon SNS topic** for receiving notifications. **Subscribe an email address** to receive the notifications. This SNS topic can be used for all notifications, so only needs to be created once.

Then, create a **User Data script** to configure the alarm. I recommend using the **[AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)**. The example below assumes Linux, but you could do similar in Windows, especially PowerShell.

First, grab the InstanceId:

```
instance=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/`
```

Then, **create an alarm** to trigger when CPU drops below 10%, measured on an hourly average, over a period of 24 hours:

> aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name low-cpu --alarm-description "Alarm when CPU drops below 10% over a day" --metric-name CPUUtilization --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistic Average --period 3600 --threshold 10 --comparison-operator LessThanThreshold  --dimensions  Name=InstanceId,Value=$instance --evaluation-periods 24 --alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MyTopic --unit Percent

The actual values might take some tweaking to get the results you desire.

**Alternatively**, you could just write a script that runs on the instance itself, monitors itself, and sends out an email without involving CloudWatch. Less moving parts!

Comment: For my use-case, I have to get notify when machine goes off. As per this metric, I can get notify. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863805/how-do-i-set-an-alarm-to-terminate-an-ec2-instance-using-boto

I can also put bootstrap action, but problem here is, in bootstrapping step, there is no metric of given instanceId. 

can you suggest some solution for my use-case ?

Comment: @Devsda -- Please create a new Question on StackOverflow rather than asking a new question in the Comments section.

Answer (score 0):

John Rotenstein is correct. What is required is to create an SNS topic, subscribe to it, and create a CloudWatch alarm on "CPUUtilization" metric. In order to do this automatically, either these steps need to be executed at the time when a new instance is started, or baked-in into the base AMI from which new instances are launched!

You can refer to [AwsWinSysOps](http://github.com/akashawasthi/AwsWinSysOps) for a quick-start guide to setting it up.

> AwsWinSysOps is a quick-start guide and package for monitoring AWS EC2
>   windows instances using AWS CloudWatch metrics.