# monitor ec2 instances lifecycle

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring

Hi I am new to AWS and I started learning now. In my environment I noticed all the issues are getting raised by autoscaling only. Whenever new instances comes up there are some small issues happening in environment. So I thought if we have a script to trigger a alert whenever any ec2 instance get reboots or terminates or any new instance spins up but I do not have a idea how to achieve it.

While checking with AWS support they are pointing cloudwatch where we need to trigger alarm for each instance. When we have huge number of instances and multiple environments, setting up a alarm for individual instance is hectic job. Can anyone suggest how can I get information about a instance reboot, termination and new instance spin up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create SNS notification whenever auto scaling scales.

Read [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/ASGettingNotifications.html)

You can write your script in your favourite language which can subscribe to the particular SNS topic.

Comment: Hi Jayaprakash, SNS notification is for autoscaling but i want notification for every event like manual termination or reboot also. Please help me to know how to get the information of API call.

Comment: Then you should use Cloud Watch alarm to get notify as you said. Creating cloud watch alarm can also be automated by using user data - Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002240/aws-cloudwatch-alarm-on-startup-of-new-ec2-instance

Comment: Hi Jayaprakash, by using cloudwatch we may have to configure for every instance, instead as it is mentioned in the above mentioned link I want to write a script to find all API calls for RunInstances
StartInstances, 
StopInstances, 
TerminateInstances. 
RebootInstances, 
AttachInstances. But I dont know where and how to query it. Can you please give a clue. Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned in the above link, you can pass user data script when instance launch where you can write script to set a cloud watch alarm. This way you can reduce the manual configuration. Since you asked about the API calls, have a look at it - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html